Ubuntu freezes while accessing microfone driver
i'm very new to Linux/Ubuntu and don't realy know what informations i have to deliver here. Espacialy with some log outputs or something else please just let me know what is needed. It would be great if i could improve my linux skills with this problem.
But enough introduction, here comes the problem:
Every time i try to use my microfone the system is getting freezed for all the time, just a hard reset is working for me.This happens when i go into the system settings (because they are getting opened on a screen where the microfone is effected) or when i' trying to use the mice with discord, signal or whatsapp-web. The sound in background is still working.
Another information, maybe important, maybe not?:
There are several sound output-devices connected to my desktop-pc.
The ones that are working are:

Sound in screen, connected via HDMI
headphone, connected with the front-headphone-port (internal directly connected to the mainboard

The ones that is not working:

sound system, connected to the line-out from the mainboard at the back of my tower

It would be great to get help here!
Kind regards!
And have a great weak!

Open the terminal and run sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade: this will search (also) for new versions of drivers. During this process, Ubuntu will probably ask you for permission to install the new versions of packages; type "Y" when requested to consent.
If this doesn't work you have to install some drivers built specifically for your external device, so it's useful to specify the type of microphone you're configuring. Before that, even if it may sound trivial, check if your device works with another computer.
Little suggestion: instead of force reloading, try shutting down the system safely with the keys combination Alt + Sys (Rsyst on some keyboards) and (keep holding alt but not Sys) writing REISUB. If your machine doesn't respond, force reboot by pressing the power button.
Feel free to ask for clarification or more info!

thx for your reply!
The update/upgrade was not solving the problem.
stupid question: What is "sys"? The "windows"-key? shutting down the computer by pressing the power button was possible.
Further i try some things. I recognized that all is working when i disconnect the microphone physically, so plug off the usb cable. If i reconnect it, it is freezing imediatly.
I'm actually trying to find a driver for the microphone which is working on the same pc on windows. (Neewer mic)

No problem: "Sys" is the key on the right of  F12, sometimes with the label "Print Rsyst".
The instantaneous freezing it's quite strange to me, sincerely;  search if your mic needs some drivers: in that case, you will find them on your mic industry website, or in a guide provided by them with the product.
